# This program should output a number of primes, but when i input "total" it doesn't start.Where is the mistake?

Tags: c

```
/* Program Print Prime Numbers */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int *primes=NULL;
    int trial=0;
    bool found=false;
    size_t total=0;
    size_t count=0;

    printf("\nHow many primes would you like?\n");
    scanf("%d",&total);
    total=(total<4?4:total);
    printf("%d",total);

    primes= (int*)malloc(total*sizeof(int));
    if(primes==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNot enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    *primes=2;
    *(primes+1)=3;
    *(primes+2)=5;
    count=3;
    trial=5;

    while(count<total);
    {
        trial+=2;
        for(size_t i=0;i<count;i++)
            if(!(found=(trial % *(primes+i)))) 
                if(found)
                  *(primes+count++)=trial;
    }

    for(size_t i=0;i<total;i++)
    {
        if(!(i%5))
          printf("\n");
        printf("%d",*(primes+i));
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This a C program from a book that i use to learn C Programming.
   This program doesn't work.
   When it should input the "total" variable, the program continue to input values.
   How many primes would you like?
   4
   5
   10...like this

Comment: where's the indentation

Comment: Did you press enter, after typing the number?

Comment: `if(!(found=(trial % *(primes+i))))` ?? is it should be `if(!(found  == (trial % *(primes+i))))`, you don't  increment `counts`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I don't think this is a source of the problem. It's definitely very bad style. But the OP's logic seems okay.

Comment: Very bad idea to use `%d` with a variable of type `size_t`, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with `scanf()` or `enter` as some suggested - this could be easily seen by `fflush`ing the output after the first `printf`.

I found the source for your code, and you forgot a little important `break` which does all the difference:

```
while(count<total)
{
    trial+=2;
    for(size_t i=0;i<count;i++)
        if(!(found=(trial % *(primes+i))))
            break;  // <-------------------- HERE.
        if(found)
            *(primes+count++)=trial;
}
```

Also, as suggested, there should be no trailing semicolon after the `while` clause-opening.

Comment: Thanks.I removed the semicolon and now it works.The break statement was initialy there by i deleted when i want to "fix" the program.

Answer (score 4):

> ... but when i input “total” it doesn't start.Where is the mistake?

Without commenting about the other problems, the reason that it doesn't start is that it goes into an infinite loop because you say:

```
while(count<total);
```

Remove the trailing `;`.

Comment: Thank very much.This was the problem.I removed the ; and now it works.And of course i added the BREAK; statement .

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` is blocking call reading input from `stdin` until `EOL` is read. This means you have to start the program, type the desired number of primes and press enter, to end the input.

EDIT:
Some clarifications:

`stdin` is standart input. By default it's keyboard input.

`EOL` means end of line. It's a character marking end of line.

Blocking call means, that the program stops until the the call is finished. Functions for input are generally speaking blocking. Very simply put, the program is removed from processor, no instructions are executed, until the call is finished, unblocking the program.

Answer (score 0):

Just press "Enter" button to force your "scanf" to return its read value